# Sidekiq connection. What is a connection to Redis?

Tags: redis, sidekiq

I'm having a little trouble understanding this config segment:

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { size: SIDEKIQ_THREADS }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.options['concurrency'] = SIDEKIQ_THREADS
```

It looks like the client (the part of redis that enqueues jobs in Redis) can be configured to have a number of connections to Redis. Does this make the enqueueing of jobs faster in some way?

What does the concurrency option do?

Answer (score 0):

The client can be multithreaded, e.g. Puma.  In this case it helps to have multiple connections that can be used by all the threads.